# Hiding the URL of one site's pdf under another site

Tags: java, url, pdf, spark-java

I am trying to make a API that allows its users to read pdfs through their browser however the pdfs are stored on 2 different sources.  One being on our systems and the other through a 3rd party's site (E.g. http://site2.com/aFile.pdf).

Basically we want the user to never know which source they are reading from.  I was using java-spark's response.redirect(http://site2.com/aFile.pdf) function until I was informed of this, so now I'm wondering how to alter the code to display the pdf of site2 through our site's pathing (E.g. http://site1.com/pdfReader).

I'm pretty sure response.redirect() is going in the wrong direction now, wondering if there's a different route.

Thanks,

Comment: Although I don't use Spark, I could probably help by looking into it. The problem is, you don't specify any types or include any references to the documentation. I don't know what `response` is, I couldn't find `URL1` or `URL2` in the javadocs. You are limiting who can answer this question by excluding such information.

Comment: There, cleaned things up

Comment: @VinceEmigh: http://sparkjava.com/

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Not sure what your goal is by linking me to the site. Do you expect me to study the entire framework?

Comment: @VinceEmigh you wrote _The problem is, you don't specify any types or include any references to the documentation_. So I just referenced it.